# Import into Elasticsearch from repeatedly created JSON but store old values

Tags: mysql, json, elasticsearch, timestamp, kibana

New to Elasticsearch and Kibana so please bear with me. I'm not using Logstash but JSON files to import the information I need. Basically, Kibana is used for monitoring change in values in MySQL database over time. Right now, transfer of information works by a script to 1)delete previous versions of JSON files containing my information, 2)export MySQL information into JSON format files, and 3)Re-importing the newly created JSON files.

Each row of my data has a timestamp. Here comes the problem. The old versions of the information I imported are no longer reflected in Kibana (maybe cause the previous files I deleted?). Is there a way to keep the information with the old timestamps and simultaneously import the new ones?

Comment: I think that if you delete the old documents, kibana indeed won't show them.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to leave the old documents in elasticsearch and insert new ones, then you would be able to see/manage/etc both.  Elasticsearch will issue new IDs for the new documents, and all should be well.